# Trouble with membership providers

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm having a spot of trouble with ASP.NET 4.0 memberships. I want to have all my membership configuration in my web.config file and not use machine.config. I am storing the membership in a remote SQL Server 2008 R2 database server called MYSERVER\A. Here's the relevant sections of web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MarksDB" connectionString="Server=MYSQLSERVER\A;Database=test_d; Trusted_Connection=Yes; Application Name=MarksDB"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>

<authorization>
   <allow roles="Admins" />
   <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="MarksDB" />
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="MarksDBMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add 
      name="MarksDBMembershipProvider" 
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
      connectionStringName="MarksDB" 
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
      enablePasswordReset="true" 
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
      applicationName="MarksDBMembershipProvider" 
      requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
      passwordFormat="Hashed" 
      maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
      minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
      passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
      passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>

  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MarksDBRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add 
        name="MarksDBRoleProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
        connectionStringName="MarksDB"
        applicationName="MarksDBRoleProvider"
        />        
  </providers>      
</roleManager>
```

In Visual Studio 2010, when I go to WebSite->ASP.NET Configuration, and click Add User on the Security tab, I get this error:

```
An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again.

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: The connection name 'MarksDB' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty. at System.Web.Util.SecUtility.GetConnectionString(NameValueCollection config) at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.Initialize(String name, NameValueCollection config) at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType)
```

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `applicationName` attribute both in membership provider and in role manager to specify your application (because you could have another application using the same database). But you are specifying the `Application Name` in the connection string.

I believe you would remove the `applicationName` from membership provider and from role provider.

Comment: I removed the applicationName property from the membership provider and role provider in my web.config but I still get the same error when I click Create User.

Comment: I restored my machine.config and all is working now. Bizarre because I'm not reading anything from there.